# How to use pg_squeeze on Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I tried to make / cmake pg_squeeze on Windows but it failed.

> C:\pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10>cmake c:\pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10 CMake
>   Error: The source directory "C:/pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10" does not
>   appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press
>   the help button on the CMake GUI.

Is there any possibility to use `pg_squeeze` on Windows?
Are there any other extensions for Postgresql 9.6 and above to work on Windows for routine database maintenance?

> C:\pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10>cmake c:\pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10 CMake
>   Error: The source directory "C:/pg_squeeze-REL1_0_PG_10" does not
>   appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press
>   the help button on the CMake GUI.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other extensions for Postgresql 9.6 and above to work on Windows for routine database maintenance?

Yes, there's [pgcompacttable](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable) Here's how to make it work on Windows:

0.) Enter PostgreSQL's CLI
psql --username=postgres --dbname *your_db*

Enable extension pgstattuple for that table
CREATE EXTENSION pgstattuple;

1.) Install [ActivePerl](https://www.activestate.com/products/perl/downloads/)
2.) Open [pgcompacttable](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable/blob/master/bin/pgcompacttable) in text editor and Find-Replace
`getpwuid($<)`
with
`getlogin()`
3.) Replace
`my $user_login = $ENV{LOGNAME} || $ENV{USER} || getpwuid($<);`
with
`my $db_user = '';`
4.)
`set /p PGPASSWORD="Enter password: "`
`set PGUSER=postgres`
`set PGHOST=127.0.0.1`
`set PGPORT=5432`
`%SystemDrive%\perl64\bin\perl.exe pgcompacttable --dbname *your_db* -f >> pgcompacttable.log`